# No permission to build from an other project jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to use an other project to promote my builds.
I am using this plugin  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin

But I have the following error message when I am linking a project

[image: error message]

This is working but not really properly.
Promotion logs:

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/generator-api
Promoting generator-api #86
build hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BuildTrigger@36339454 SUCCESS
Warning: this build has no associated authentication, so build permissions may be lacking, and downstream projects which cannot even be seen by an anonymous user will be silently skipped
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I should have the deploy build there as well.

I can't find how to give permission to my project to build deploy when promoting.

Comment: How do you manage the permissions for your Jenkins instance? Is it a role based or matrix based strategy (or something else)?

Comment: In `authorisation` I have `Logged-in users can do anything`

Comment: Did you set some specific permissions on the new job or on the "deploy“ job?

Comment: in `Configure Build Authorization` I have `Run as User who Triggered Build` for both

Comment: Hi! Are you found solution for this? I got the same "permission" error =(

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the downstream project should have `Run as User who Triggered Build` options selected in `Configure Build Authorization` section.

In my case that options is missing. To enable that see following Jenkins plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin

**EDIT**
I solved the problem in different way. I had this code in execute shell of promote section:

```
git tag -d DEVENV
git tag DEVENV ${PROMOTED_GIT_COMMIT}
git push origin --tags —force
```

Problem was that the tag didn't exist and the script was failing on the first line trying to delete it.

***It is very likely that the auth warning message is vague and hides different problems.***

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue when trying to add new trigger for building another project, and this seems to resolve it:

With the *Authorize Project plugin*, you should go to "**Access Control for Builds**" section, in the *Global Security* at`https://{your-jenkins-domain}/configureSecurity/`:
[image]

Adding a new strategy "Run as SYSTEM", allowed the Jenkins Cron scheduler to trigger build on another project.

Note however, that the red warning "You have no permission to build" did not disappeared, although it did not prevent the triggered build to be launched by the scheduler.